# NSGraphicsContext becomes NULL after setting CAMetalLayer

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview, metal

I trying to move my NSView based application to start using GPU with Metal. So, I added a `CAMetalLayer` using like this:

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize;
```

And make the backing layer, like this:

```
- (CALayer*)makeBackingLayer
{
    id <MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    CAMetalLayer *backingLayer   = [CAMetalLayer layer];
    backingLayer.opaque          = YES;
    backingLayer.device          = device;
    backingLayer.pixelFormat     = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    backingLayer.framebufferOnly = YES;

    [backingLayer setDelegate:self];
    return backingLayer;
}
```

I write all this code in my `CustomNSView` class is inherited from a `CustomParentNSView` class which uses `NSGraphicsContext` to draw some things on the screen. Now, since I am moving `CustomNSView` to a layer backed NSView, when I try to call:

```
[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
```

This returns NULL.

1. Should this be NULL for layer backed NSViews?

I also tried investigating where in the previous implementation `NSGraphicsContext` was getting generated, and it turns out, my application was setting it nowhere. `NSView` was itself setting the `NSGraphicsContext` from somewhere inside of `displayIfNeeded`, before calling `drawRect`.

2. Can I still use NSGraphicsContext to render to NSView, even when it is layer backed?

Thanks!

Comment: When (in what context) are you calling `[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]`? What do you expect that context to draw to? If you want to draw using `NSGraphicsContext`, don't use a Metal layer. Just use a normal layer.

Comment: @KenThomases The reason I am using Metal Layer, is because I first want to do some drawing using the GPU, and then draw some Cocoa constructs over the drawing made from GPU. Earlier I was on OpenGL so, I never faced this issue. I expect the context to draw to the same NSView, to which GPU drew.

Comment: That won't work. Metal layers and Cocoa drawing are mutually exclusive. You should add a subview or subviews to the view using the Metal layer. Those subviews can draw other stuff to appear on top of the Metal-drawn content.

Comment: @KenThomases is there any documentation that explains this exclusive behaviour in more detail?! Thanks for the information though :-)

Comment: Well, the [docs for `CAMetalLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer) say "To render the layer’s content, use the nextDrawable method to retrieve a texture, then use it as a render target in a Metal rendering pipeline." That is, there's no other way to render such a layer's content.

Comment: @KenThomases I tried replacing the Metal layer with `CAOpenGLLayer` just to verify if I get an `NSGraphicsContext` context there, turns out `currentContext` is `NULL` with `CAOpenGLLayer` as well. So, are we sayin, that `NSGraphicsContext` drawing is not possible with any layer?

Comment: Plus, in `CALayerDelegate` I see a method `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`, though I am currently not able to get this function called, should this function not be usable with `CAMetalLayer` as well?

Comment: Both OpenGL and Metal are special. They need unusual access to the frame buffer. They are incompatible with normal Cocoa drawing. Other kinds of layers do work with Cocoa drawing.

Comment: One other strange thing that I observed was that `getRectsBeingDrawn:count` now does not return any rects, since I get a `displayLayer` call and not a drawRect` call. Are the dirtyRects only set by call to `setNeedsDisplayInRect:updatedRect` or is there any other way to set dirty rects as well, that differ in layers? @KenThomases

Comment: Yes, dirty rects are only set by the `-setNeedsDisplay...` methods. Also, with a Metal layer, you can't really draw only parts. You have to redraw the whole thing. You're drawing to a different texture and then replacing the on-screen content with that texture. If you fail to draw (or at least clear) some parts of the texture, they'll just be junk.

Comment: @KenThomases I tried using `setNeedsDisplayInRect` and `getRectsBeingDrawn` from NSView, after I have made my NSView as layer backed, and `getRectsBeingDrawn` tends to return empty rects all the time. Is this behavior because we are expected to draw everything instead of a part of view?